# Query that works in MYSQL but not SQLite ( Syntax difference? )

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Hi I have a query that selects all the houses from my houses table that are grouped by street address. It counts how many are on that street but also counts how many on that street are referenced in another canvass table.

I have the query working in MYSQL but when I try it with SQlite in my iOS app it doesn't work. Is there some syntax differences between the two I am unaware of?

```
 SELECT haddress AS hd, COUNT( * ) ,
    (
     SELECT COUNT( * ) 
     FROM canvass, house
     WHERE canvass.hid = house.hid
     AND house.haddress = hd
    )
 FROM house
 GROUP BY haddress
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you can't reference column aliases in inner queries on SQLite, so you'll have to change your inner query slightly to use an alias for `house` so you can reference the outer `house.haddress`. The altered query should work on both SQLite and MySQL;

```
SELECT haddress AS hd, COUNT( * ),
    (
     SELECT COUNT( * ) 
     FROM canvass, house house2
     WHERE canvass.hid = house2.hid
     AND house2.haddress = house.haddress
    )
FROM house
GROUP BY haddress
```